# Help in finding cause of Xorg crash

Tags: 20.04, xorg, crash, amdgpu, boinc

I need your help to find the cause of a X server crash caused by the application "BOINC Manager".
This app has been working fine for almost a year until two days ago: after turning my computer on, I ran BOINC Manager and the system crashed as soon as the window showed.
The system is up to date. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
The problem can be reproduced, as it happens every time I open the app.
Here are the logs and other info: (To help you to search through the logs, the last crash was on 08-05-2022 19:54:31)

[/var/log/syslog](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fDB84p3q33/)

[/var/log/apport.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Pq7jhst47k/)

[Backtrace of core dump from /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WDDnXKZjHW/)

[~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rJwqMpHm7k/)

[Output of lshw](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/k6t8GzbgN4/)

Please feel free to ask for any other important info. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Completely purging the AMD Radeon drivers, rebooting, reinstalling them again and rebooting seems to have solved the problem.

I didn't have to reinstall boinc-manager.